# swift JSONDecoder is not working

Tags: ios, swift

I watch WWDC session 102 and I try to use JSONDecoder to model,but I have a question,this is my struct

```
public struct DataListResult:Codable{
    let _id : String
    let createdAt : String
    let desc : String
    let images : Array<String>
    let publishedAt : String
    let source : String
    let type : String
    let url : String
    let used : Int
    let who : String
}

public struct DataListModel:Codable{

    let results : [DataListResult]
    let error: Bool
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "results" : [
    {
      "_id" : "59266a79421aa92c73b6475c",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/img.gank.io\/875a9508-3a1e-4d4b-8b91-c111ea62871a"
      ],
      "source" : "chrome",
      "who" : "S",
      "publishedAt" : "2017-05-25T13:32:48.92Z",
      "used" : true,
      "createdAt" : "2017-05-25T13:24:09.35Z",
      "type" : "iOS",
      "desc" : "iOS ",
      "url" : "https:\/\/github.com\/adamzjk\/iOS-ObjectDetection"
    },
    {
      "_id" : "592502d6421aa92c769a8bac",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/img.gank.io\/44e8aa0a-b66f-4a5b-9cb0-74c3ae9fc156"
      ],
      "source" : "chrome",
      "who" : "S",
      "publishedAt" : "2017-05-24T12:09:25.526Z",
      "used" : true,
      "createdAt" : "2017-05-24T11:49:42.14Z",
      "type" : "iOS",
      "desc" : "Whatʼs new in Swift 4",
      "url" : "https:\/\/github.com\/ole\/whats-new-in-swift-4"
    },
    {
      "_id" : "5923a438421aa92c73b64743",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/img.gank.io\/25762b53-b2ba-4c1c-9666-1683cd72bb82"
      ],
      "source" : "chrome",
      "who" : "who",
      "publishedAt" : "2017-05-23T11:14:05.141Z",
      "used" : true,
      "createdAt" : "2017-05-23T10:53:44.853Z",
      "type" : "iOS",
      "desc" : "music",
      "url" : "https:\/\/github.com\/HarshilShah\/DeckTransition"
    }
  ],
  "error" : false
}
```

The property `images` can't decoded,because I remove this it can be success,but I don't know how to fix,please tell me, thank you

```
 do
            {
                let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(DataListModel.self, from: response.data!)

            }catch let error as NSError {

               print("\(error)") //Error Domain=Swift.DecodingError Code=2 "(null)"


            }
```

--------- last update 2017.6.17 ----------

```
let images : Array<String> -> let images : Array<String>?
```

images need opotional property when it empty,thank you for your help

Comment: `let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(DataListModel.self, from: data)` worked fine for me with the JSON and structs you provided in your question, with no error. Edit your question to show us how you decoded it and the precise error you got.

Answer (score 11):

The property `used` is supposed to be `Bool` but the structure is decoded correctly with

```
do {
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(DataListModel.self, from: data)
    print(decoded)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

assuming `data` is the JSON `Data` object.

Comment: I am update my question, The property `Image` can't decoded,because I remove this it can be success

Comment: same issue here

Comment: @Karim did you find solution, I am having same issue